# Cobrança de Tráfego em Sistema SaaS

Tags: saas

Gostaria de saber se o `tráfego` consumido pelos Robôs de Busca, é contabilizado junto com os de usuários em um sistema `SaaS`.

Ou a cobrança é feita somente pela navegação genuína via `browser`?

Algumas plataformas `SaaS` cobram por pageviews, visitas ou tráfego, um exemplo são as plataformas de multi-lojas, limita o lojista em `tráfego` "Banda contabilizada nas visualizações de fotos, output do htmls, css, etc", `pageviews`, `visitas únicas` ou `produtos`.

Minha dúvida consiste em saber, se a `banda` consumida por cada loja separadamente, envolve os robôs de busca ( `bot`, `crawler`, `spider` ), pois estes também consome banda do servidor.

Desde já agradeço. ;)

Comment: Você está falando do tráfego no provedor de hospedage?

Comment: @KaduAmaral, não não, tráfego consumido por cada conta em um sistema SaaS. Exemplo o cara tem uma loja virtual, e a cada visualização de uma página, é contabilizado pageviews, visitas ou tráfego, para que se faça a cobrança, minha dúvida é, se entra o tráfego do robos de busca na contabilidade, sendo que o mesmo vai consumir banda do meu servidor.

Comment: O custo gerado por motores de busca, normalmente, são bem baixos. Acho que a pergunta que você deveria fazer é: **Quanto será cobrado num [DDoS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_servi%C3%A7o)?** Pois milhares de acessos inúteis ao seu site podem torrar todo o seu orçamento rapidamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom vamos lá, é um pouco complexo de responder isso, tudo vai depender realmente o que o seu `SaaS` "olha", contabilizar tráfego é bem diferente de se contabilizar visualizações.

Imagine que o seu SaaS olhe somente tráfego, esse tipo de controle é feito monitorando a porta do Switch Layer 3 na qual o serviço roda, se for algo virtualizado cada loja pode estar separada por Vlans, tudo que trafega na porta/vlan é somado (upload/download), no fim do mês o cara tem o seu tráfego de upload e download independente, eu duvido que eles tenham um sniffer por trás tirando da soma quais ips são robôs conhecidos, isso seria um trabalho brutal e inviável (e se o IP ou classe de um dos robôs mudar?), portanto eu duvido que alguém desconte do tráfego robôs colhendo informações.

Pois bem imagine agora que o SaaS olhe a quantidade de visitas, a única maneira que eu conheço de se contabilizar isso é analisando os logs de acesso do servidor http, dependendo do verbose do log tem muita informação de quem se conectou (IP, Agent, Versao do SO, etc), mais uma vez o seu SaaS teria que saber quais destes visitantes são robôs, descontar agentes que não sejam considerados de usuários. É possível? sim é possível excluir os conhecidos! o google por exemplo disponibiliza informações de como os acessos de um bot deles apareceriam nos seus logs veja [aqui](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en).

A questão é saber se estas empresas se preocupam em reunir informações e padrões de bots. na minha opinião isso não é feito.

Imagine que o senhor José desenvolva na casa dele um robô que se conecte a sua loja virtual e compare o preço de um barbeador elétrico com outras lojas? e ai você acha o que o seu SaaS teria artifícios suficientes para identificar isso? tanto por tráfego quanto por acesso essa conexão passaria tranquilamente como um usuário, ainda mas se o robô do Senhor José enviar informações de agentes e SO exatamente como se fosse de um usuário verdadeiro (se passaria pelo que você chamou de navegação genuína por browser), e pior imagine que esse robô faça ao longo do dia 30 acessos, como saber se realmente não era um usuário clicando F5 a espera de uma promoção relâmpago em sua loja.

O caminho correto é você questionar diretamente onde roda seus serviços, eles podem dizer que não contabilizam mas mesmo assim eu duvido rsrs.

Answer (score 2):

Se você estiver hospedando um e-commerce e os crawlers navegarem através do site será contabilizado.

O que você pode fazer para evitar o consumo é utilizar o famoso robots.txt.

Exemplo de robots.txt (Google)
http://www.google.com/robots.txt

Gerador de Robots.txt:
http://www.mcanerin.com/EN/search-engine/robots-txt.asp

Referências:
https://moz.com/blog/12-ways-to-keep-your-content-hidden-from-the-search-engines